# My SOAP web service function doesn't return anything

Tags: web-services, codeigniter, soap, wsdl

I'm using Codeigniter and trying to write a soap web service which is like this:
Everything looks fine I get the functions list Ok in wsdl and can call them correctly, but the thing is the functions looks are not called, because everytime I call them it return null, I put a counter in **authenticateUser** and I checked it everytime I called the method, no change, Where Is my problem.

```
class Webservice extends CI_Controller
{
        function Webservice()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->ns = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/webservice/';
                $this->load->library("nusoap_lib");
                $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server();
                $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("Iranmanesh law center web services", $this->ns);
                $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $this->ns;
                $this->nusoap_server->register('getMyTasks', array ('UserID' => "xsd:string", 'Password' => "xsd:string"), array ("return" => "xsd:integer"), "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$this->ns."/getMyTasks", "rpc", "encoded", "Get user`s tasks");
                $this->nusoap_server->register('updateTask', array ('UserID' => "xsd:string",'Password' => "xsd:string",'TaskID'=>'xsd:string','Description'=>'xsd:string','Status'=>'char'), array ("return" => "xsd:integer"), "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$this->ns."/updateTask", "rpc", "encoded", "Get user`s tasks");
                $this->nusoap_server->register('authenticateUser', array ('Username' => "xsd:string", 'Password' => "xsd:string"), array ("return" => "xsd:string"), "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$this->ns."/authenticateUser", "rpc", "encoded", "Authenticate users");
        }
        public function index()
        {
                function authenticateUser($Username=nuul,$Password=null)
                {
                        $this->load->model('counter_model');
                        $this->counter_model->update_page($Username);
                        $UserInfo=array(
                                'user'=>array('userID'=>1,'Username'=>'user','Name'=>'Masoud')
                        );
                        $Output='<user><userID>1</userID><Username>user</Username><Name>Masoud</Name></user>';
                        //return $UserInfo;
                        return TRUE;
                }
                function getMyTasks($UserID,$Password)
                {
                        $Tasks=array('task'=>
                                array('ID'=>'12','Title'=>'Go to court','Description'=>'Go to court in 3/3/1393 for Mr. Rezae','Date'=>'2012-02-23','Status'=>'U','Message'=>'It`s not done yet')
                        );
                        return $Tasks;
                }
                function updateTask($UserID,$Password,$TaskID,$Description=null,$Status)
                {
                        return array('Success'=>true);
                }
                $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        }

}
```

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the endpoints with a regular browser? Is there anything in your error logs?

Comment: Hey man, it's in my log: "GET /webservice?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 3916 "-" "-" ::1 - - [13/Jul/2014:19:44:51 +0430] "POST /index.php/webservice HTTP/1.1" 200 160 "-" "PHP-SOAP/5.4.7" , doesn't look any error, and I don't know how to hitting the endpoint with browser, I'm new to webservice , would you please tell me what to do, thanks a million

Comment: It works fine in my localhost, but it returns null in host I upload